# MySQL Joins table with SUM

Tags: mysql

how to execute a "MySQL" query for all values that are in my column ?

Here is my table

```
Table A
|------------------|
|     horse        |    
|------------------|
|     C.Ferland    |
|     Abrivard     |
|     P. Hawas     |
|------------------|

Table B 

|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          id          |        CL           |     horse        |    
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|           1          |        1er          |     C.Ferland    |
|           2          |        5e           |     Abrivard     |
|           3          |        3e           |     P. Hawas     |
|           4          |        7e           |     Rafin        |
|           5          |        3e           |     edouard      |
|           6          |        6e           |     Loui         |
|           8          |        12e          |     Elsa         |
|           9          |        8e           |     Jseph        |
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want the output to be:

```
+------------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+
|    horse   | Top_1  | Top_2_3 | TOP_4_5 | TOP_total |
+------------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+
| C. Ferland | 0.1757 |  0.2788 |  0.1892 |    0.6436 |
|  Abrivard  | 0.0394 |  0.1231 |  0.1575 |    0.3199 |
| P. Hawas   | 0.0461 |  0.1263 |  0.1092 |    0.2816 |
+------------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Currently, I'm using this query for a table and it's very good.

```
select
    horse
    sum(cl = 1)      / count(*) over() top_1,
    sum(cl in (2,3)) / count(*) over() top_2_3,
    sum(cl in (4,5)) / count(*) over() top_4_5,
    sum(cl <= 5)     / count(*) over() top_1_5
from p_mu.jour
group by horse
```

How to join the column table A with the CL of my table B

Comment: It's best to sync table and names published with query. Where for example is jockey?

Comment: it is a mistake Jockey = horse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a join.
Use the operator IN:

```
select t.*
from (
  select
    horse,
    sum(cl = 1)      / count(*) over() top_1,
    sum(cl in (2,3)) / count(*) over() top_2_3,
    sum(cl in (4,5)) / count(*) over() top_4_5,
    sum(cl <= 5)     / count(*) over() top_1_5
  from p_mu.jour
  group by horse
) t
where t.horse in (select horse from TableA)
```

or EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from (
  select
    horse,
    sum(cl = 1)      / count(*) over() top_1,
    sum(cl in (2,3)) / count(*) over() top_2_3,
    sum(cl in (4,5)) / count(*) over() top_4_5,
    sum(cl <= 5)     / count(*) over() top_1_5
  from p_mu.jour
  group by horse
) t
where exists (select 1 from TableA where horse = t.horse)
```

Comment: I don't understand the Select 't. *' .. and
) t .. and select 1?

Comment: `t` is the alias of your query which in my code is a subquery. `select t.*...` means select all the columns of that subquery aliased t. The `where` clause in the end will filter the results of your query so only horses that exist in TableA will be returned. The `1` in `select 1` is just a column placeholder. It could be `select 0` or `select null`, it doesn't matter. What is important here is that there exists a row in TableA with the same horse as in `t`.

Comment: I must necessarily make an error in the reproduction of the query I have an error message

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum(cl = 1)      / count(*) over() top_1,
    sum(cl in (2,3)) / count(*) over()' at line 5

Comment: A comma was missing after `select horse` from my code and your code. I edited.

Comment: p_mu.cachedate est ma  table_B

Comment: p_mu.jockey is my table A

Comment: select t.*
from (
  select
    jockey
    sum(cl = 1)      / count(*) over() top_1,
    sum(cl in (2,3)) / count(*) over() top_2_3,
    sum(cl in (4,5)) / count(*) over() top_4_5,
    sum(cl <= 5)     / count(*) over() top_1_5
  from p_mu.cachedate AS table_B 
  group by jockey
) t
where exists (select 1 from p_mu.jockey where jockey = t.jockey);

Comment: See my previous comment. There was a typo: missing comma.

Comment: you just saved me 3 to 4 days of research ... Thank you

Comment: your query function very well